# How to update from WP 8.0 to 8.1 on mobile data?

Tags: 8.1, update, cellular-data

I need to update my Lumia 520 from Windows Phone 8.0 to 8.1, but it is not allowing me to download it over the mobile data and I don't have any wifi access.

Is there any way to manually override this so I can download the update on mobile data?

Comment: What firmware version are you running? Check Settings > Extras+Info and see what it reports as "Software release". If I recall correctly, the ability to download OS updates over a cellular connection was added in GDR3 (Lumia Black), so if you have an earlier version, Wi-Fi might be your only option.

Comment: its says as Lumia Amber.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate. You can vote to reopen if you feel that it is not.